# Proper use of the definite article in "competitive advantage through the use of technology"

Tags: definite-article

I am not a native speaker of English and I really struggle with proper use of word "the". I have done quite a bit of research and I always seem to get it wrong. Anyway, I would appreciate if someone can help me with this sentence:

> I work with leading organizations globally to help them gain competitive advantage through the use of technology and through embarkment of cultural transformations.

1. Do I need to add "the" in front of "use"?
2. Do I need to add "the" in front of "embarkment"?

Thanks! 
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I work with leading organizations globally to help them gain **a**
>   competitive advantage through **the** use of technology and through
>   **the** embarkation of cultural transformations.

Nouns always require an article except when they refer to collective nouns used in a non-specific context.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Curtis! In terms of "embarkation", I am referring to the notion of how companies start or begin a transformation process, and the whole journey of it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, I see. You typed "embankment" which refers to something entirely different.

Comment: Thanks - looks like I had a spelling mistake there. I've changed it to "embarkment".

Comment: I adjusted my answer to reflect this.